# Where is an image's "alt" value stored?

Tags: shopify

In Shopify, when you assign an Image Alt Text to an image using the online editor, where is that value stored? Apparently, it is not stored in config/settings_data.json of the theme code.

Now I saw that my liquid code has

```
{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '580x', scale: 2 | img_tag: block.settings.image.alt, 'lazyload transition-in' }}
```

which means the alt tag value should come from settings, however that's not the case. It is stored somewhere, but I am not able to find in the theme code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alt attribute is stored internally for the object.

For example when you set a title for the product the title is not stored as a setting, but it's applied internally to that object.

In your example you have a block image, you target the image using `block.settings.image` and from there on you have access to all of the image properties seen in here https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/image and ALT is one of them.

The file `settings_data.json` stores only information from settings_schema and all of the sections options.

Comment: does that mean that there is no way to change 'ALT' values on images when doing local development? Is online editor the ONLY way to add 'ALT' info to images?

Comment: @Vishal Don't quite get your question. You write the IMG tag yourself and you have the option to add what you want to the ALT, if you like to use the entered one from the editor you use that one, if you like to enter a static one, you enter a static one.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. What I mean is, local development of themes allow you to change different settings in settings_data.json, which can also be changed from online customize theme. But apparently, for ALT tags, the value is not stored in settings_data.json, rather in some internal object which I am not able to update in theme code.

Answer (score 0):

This threads a bit old now, but if anyones looking for a solution - you can grab it by:

```
{{ image.alt }}
```